# How to create a new variable after finding matches in a dataset in SAS

Tags: join, sas, matching

I have 2 SAS tables, one has data about people that have posted into a forum. For example:

[image]

And I have a table that has a list of people:

[image]

I want to match these tables to show who has posted into the forum so the new table looks like this with a new column to indicate if the person has matched with the forum table:

[image]

Comment: You should really show what you have tried or considered before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't provide this as I don't have any ideas and was hoping for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

A left join of tables `Mails` and `Posts` can be done.

Example:

Requires `ID` to be the persons common ID in the different application data tables.  You haven't provided enough details about the `ID` and `name` column roles to ensure a correct `ON` clause.

```
  select 
    Mails.ID, Mails.Name, Mails.Email
    case when Posts.Post is null then 0 else 1 end as Posted
  from
    Mails
  left join
    Posts
  on
    Mails.ID = Posts.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a SAS data step. Assuming table names are MAILS and POSTS

```
data POSTED;
merge MAILS (in=s1) POSTS (in=s2);
by ID;
if s1 and s2 then do;
   posted=1;
   output;
   end;
if s1 and not s2 then do;
   posted=0;
   output;
   end;
drop post;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your list of users is unique (only one observation per NAME) but the list of post is not (potentially multiple posts per NAME).

First make sure the data are sorted by the key variable (NAME), then MERGE the two.  You can then use the IN= dataset option to indicate if that dataset contributed to the current observation.  Looks like you only want the users to appear once no matter how many posts they made so you can use the FIRST.NAME flag.  I will also exclude posts made by names that are not in the list of names, but you could keep those, they just would have missing values for the variables (EMAIL) that come from the names dataset.  The variables created by the IN= dataset option are not written to the output dataset, so copy it to another variable that will be written.

```
proc sort data=names; by name; run;
proc sort data=posts; by name; run;
data want;
  merge names(in=innames) posts(in=inposts);
  by name;
  if first.name and innames;
  posted = inposts;
run;
```